# Embedd facebook video in my website

Tags: facebook, video

I am trying to embed Facebook video into my website. I found steps that would make it work but the problem is, if I open the website in my iPhone or any smartphone the video is not loading at all.

The information I have gathered in embedding Facebook videos is that I have to get the unique id of the video that can just be seen in the browser. Here is the sample code I have:

```
 <object width="400" height="300" >
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/UniqueVideoId" />
    <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/UniqueVideoId" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="224">
   </embed>
</object>
```

What else do I need to do to make the facebook video work on iPhone or any smart phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a video player that isn't flash based, and works on iOS or android.

You could then retrieve the raw video URL from the API and include that in your app

`SELECT vid, owner, title, description, src, src_hq, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=me()` as an FQL query will return you the details of a video, including the URL of the raw video source for including into your app (`src` and `src_hq`).

Comment: I am not familiar yet on how to implement it. I need to do a research. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Igy can you please explain me about this. How can we fetch raw URL and where can we fetch it from?

Comment: Please re-read my answer above, the raw URL is the `src` and/or `src_hq` values of the result of the API call above, which returns videos uploaded by the current user

Comment: Hi @lgy, I wanted to implement your solution now. I found a problem. I only an API business page not an app. How do i get the api key and the secret key to be able to communicate to FB and perform the FQL query?

Comment: Got it working. I used an api key and secret key of an fb personal account, I created an app. Then, get the keys. When I query it, I used the owners id. I was able to get all the videos that was uploaded. Thanks for this!